# How to implement multilevel expandable list view?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I need to implement multilevel expandable list view, something like `ExpandableListView` but with more than 2 levels.

Now I use this data structure, but if need I can change it. It's not very important.

```
public class NodeList implements Set<NodeList>

public NodeList(String name) {
        mChilds = new ArrayList<NodeList>();
        mNodeName = name;
}

NodeList root = new NodeList("root");
    NodeList lv_1 = new NodeList("level_1");
    NodeList lv_2 = new NodeList("level_2");
    NodeList lv_3 = new NodeList("level_3");
    root.add(lv_1);
    root.add(lv_2);
    root.add(lv_3);

    NodeList lv_21 = new NodeList("level_21");
    NodeList lv_22 = new NodeList("level_22");
    lv_2.add(lv_21);
    lv_2.add(lv_22);

    NodeList lv_211 = new NodeList("level_211");
    lv_21.add(lv_211);

    NodeList lv_2111 = new NodeList("level_2111");
    NodeList lv_2112 = new NodeList("level_2112");
    lv_211.add(lv_2111);
    lv_211.add(lv_2112);

    NodeList lv_31 = new NodeList("level_31");
    NodeList lv_32 = new NodeList("level_32");
    NodeList lv_33 = new NodeList("level_33");
    lv_3.add(lv_31);
    lv_3.add(lv_32);
    lv_3.add(lv_33);

    NodeList lv_321 = new NodeList("level_321");
    lv_32.add(lv_321);`
```

Can anyone tell me which is better base view and which adapter to use? What methods needs to override? Maybe someone has already developed it, because this problem occurs quite often.

Please help.

Thanks for all response!

Comment: I need something like this http://www.itjunky.info/codes/multilevel-listview-in-android/, but I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/ ....